# Flutter error: when using url_launcher plugin

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, url-launcher

```dart
Future<void> launchInBrowser(String url) async {
  Uri dir = Uri.parse(url);
  if (!await launchUrl(
    dir,
    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  )) {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

I am using url_launcher version 6.1.6 flutter plugin and when I build the app I get this error flutter build is getting error with this : Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter\flutter.pubcache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_android_6.0.21\android\build.gradle' from cache
'''

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_android_6.0.21\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':url_launcher_android_6.0.21' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':url_launcher_android_6.0.21' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> '''

I tried deleting .gradle folder I'm my app , and also deleted the plugin from host folder , nothing works.

flutter doctor -v output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.2251], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.3.8 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 52b3dc25f6 (4 days ago), 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\mo7ma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.13)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.32413.511
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\mo7ma\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.2251]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.107
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.35

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you include the link and the way you are launching the url on code-snippet

Comment: ` Future<void> launchInBrowser(String url) async {
    Uri dir = Uri.parse(url);
    if (!await launchUrl(
      dir,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    )) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  } `

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. + make sure to follow install guide

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not open my Url in flutter with Url\_launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336398/can-not-open-my-url-in-flutter-with-url-launcher)

Comment: check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336398/can-not-open-my-url-in-flutter-with-url-launcher/74338330#74338330

Comment: actually I tried all of this , flutter clean and cleaning gradle cache , unfortunatly nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: yes I also added it, but forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

I received a lint error to use foreach instead. So I played around with it, and this is the final for loop:

```
prayerRequestList.forEach(prayerReturnList.add);
```